# admob ads comes over the tabbar in ionic 6 capacitor 4

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, capacitor

I am trying to integrate Google ads on the app. We are able to show it on the page. But ads are coming on the tabbar or on the header. So either tabbar is vanished or header is vanished.

I want to display ads below the content and above the tabbar.

Basically can I show the ads in between the content.

Following is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable  } from '@angular/core';
import { AdMob, AdMobBannerSize, AdOptions,
  BannerAdOptions, BannerAdPluginEvents, BannerAdPosition, BannerAdSize,} from '@capacitor-community/admob';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mypage',
  templateUrl: './mypage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mypage.page.scss'],
})

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MyPage implements OnInit {

  tottalnoofyears: number;

  constructor() {this.initialize(); }

    async initialize() {
    const { status } = await AdMob.trackingAuthorizationStatus();

    AdMob.initialize({
      requestTrackingAuthorization: true,
      initializeForTesting: true,
    });


    this.showBanner();
  }

  async showBanner() {
    const adId = 'ca-app-pub-MYID';
    const options: BannerAdOptions = {
      adId,
      adSize: BannerAdSize.ADAPTIVE_BANNER,   
      position: BannerAdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      margin: 0,
      isTesting: false,
    };

    await AdMob.showBanner(options);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const d = new Date();
    const year = d.getFullYear();
    const startyear = 2000;
    this.tottalnoofyears = year - 2000;
  }

}
```

Comment: I believe I saw exactly this question just a few days ago, but it's gone now. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

You can add this as part of your `initialize()`-function.

When ever you open / close your ad banner, it logically will trigger a resize event. You can use this to actually grap your app body and

a) Put the bottom margin of the app to 0 if nothing is shown.

b) If your banner shows, grab its height and still respect the safe-area-space to calculate and assign the margin you need to move your tabs / content upwards.

```
this.resizeHandler = AdMob.addListener(BannerAdPluginEvents.SizeChanged, (info: AdMobBannerSize) => {
    const appMargin = info.height;
    const app: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('ion-router-outlet');

    if (appMargin === 0) {
        app.style.marginBottom = '0px';
        return;
    }

    if (appMargin > 0) {
        const body = document.querySelector('body');
        const bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(body);
        const safeAreaBottom = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue("--ion-safe-area-bottom);
        app.style.marginBottom = `calc(${safeAreaBottom} + ${appMargin}px)`;                
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Gary thanks for the reply. I tried this solution but I am not able to place the ad inside the div which I have created in the html file. Sending you code:

Comment: ad.html
-------------
<ion-content>
  <div id="ShowMyAd" style="z-index:1;background-color: transparent;height:70px;margin:0px 5px;position: relative;border:1px #000 solid;"></div>
</ion-content>

<ion-tabs>
   <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button routerDirection="root">
        <ion-label class="blackColor">Deals</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
</ion-tab-bar>
 </ion-tabs>

Comment: In AdMob.initialize I am using the code which you had mentioned. And at the end I am calling this.showBanner();

async showBanner() {
    const adId = 'ca-app-pub-MYID';
    const options: BannerAdOptions = {
      adId,
      adSize: BannerAdSize.ADAPTIVE_BANNER,   //BANNER
      position: BannerAdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER, //BOTTOM_CENTER
      margin: 0,
      isTesting: false,

      //npa: true,
      //npa set to true to see non personalized ads
    };

    await AdMob.showBanner(options);
  }

Comment: My ad is now coming below tabbar but I want this in <div id="ShowMyAd" style="z-index:1;background-color: transparent;height:70px;margin:0px 5px;position: relative;border:1px #000 solid;"></div>

Comment: I think you do not need an extra div for it, it is placed by default

Comment: Yes. Basically I want ad should come in between the content. But documentation says it is not possible for now. As those ads supports only native app and I am using capacitor and ionic which is hybrid. So can't help for now. Let's keep an eye when capacitor allow us to make this change.